# Google Or-Tools Employee Scheduling .The condition does not work properly

Tags: python, scheduling, constraint-programming, or-tools

Im using [that nurse scheduling example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling). I have   3 employee 2 shifts and 7 days and I have a contiditon that if an employee works in shift 1 he/she cannot work the next day on shift 0. here is my code and it does not work.

```
    for n in all_nurses:
      for d in all_days:
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in range(0,1))+sum(shifts[(n, (d+1)%6, s)] for s in range(1,2)) <= 1)
```

and this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G82A.png) . Nurse 2 worked on day 0 and shift 1 and next day also worked on shift1

Comment: - try to split your command, to many generator expression here...
- if you have two shift 0 and 1 why using `for s in range(0,1)` and `for s in range(1,2)`
not sure it did what you expect
- your modulo should be `%7` for seven days...

Comment: day indexes starts with 0 so Sunday is 6. and I am using for s in range(0,1) because I cant set s variable directly. when I try that I got error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your constraint:

```
for n in all_nurses:
    for d in all_days:
        model.Add(sum([shifts[(n, d, 1)], shifts[(n, (d+1)%7, 0)]]) <= 1)
```

A better formulation would be

```
for n in all_nurses:
    for d in all_days:
        model.AddBoolOr([shifts[(n, d, 1)].Not(), shifts[(n, (d + 1) % 7, 0)].Not()])
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/aa0c6c42a523ee4c23633585b86fb6d3e090f8c8/ortools/sat/samples/bool_or_sample_sat.py#L23-L28

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. still it did not work I tried something else.  `   for n in all_nurses:
      for d in all_days:
            model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, (d-1)%6, s)] for s in range(1,2))+sum(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in range(0,1)) <= 1)  ` it worked with that and code above

Comment: my bad i used `sum(a+b)...` instead of `sum([a,b])...`

Comment: `(x%7)` will range from `[0;6]`

Comment: ok. I tried again and I got this error   -->   model.Add(sum(shifts[(n, d, 1)], shifts[(n, (d+1)%7, 0)]) <= 1)
TypeError: 'IntVar' object is not iterable

Comment: Should be model.Add(shifts[(n, d, 1)] + shifts[(n, (d+1)%7, 0)] <= 1). Which is better written as model.AddBoolOr([shifts[(n, d, 1)].Not(), (shifts[(n, (d + 1) % 7, 0)].Not()])

Comment: @BerfinTanrıverdi you missed the enclosed [] inside the sum -> 'sum([....])', otherwise python take the 2 arguments as begin/end iterators...

Comment: @LaurentPerron thank you very very much. model.Add(shifts[(n, d, 1)] + shifts[(n, (d+1)%7, 0)] <= 1) that one worked. but model.AddBoolOr([shifts[(n, d, 1)].Not(), (shifts[(n, (d + 1) % 7, 0)].Not()]) that one got syntax error

Comment: @Mizux ok that one also worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: model.AddBoolOr([shifts[(n, d, 1)].Not(), shifts[(n, (d + 1) % 7, 0)].Not()])