# OR-Tools - Nurse scheduling - prevent shift gaps with binary constraints

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools, constraint-programming

I am using OR-Tools to solve a problem similar to the Nurse Scheduling problem. The difference in my case is that when I schedule a "Nurse" for a shift, they must then work consecutive days (i.e., there can be no gaps between days worked).

Most of the similar questions point to this [code](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py). I have attempted to implement the answer adapted from there. However, I am getting output solutions which do not respecting the constraints.

The logic I was trying to follow is that I want to forbid patterns that have gaps. For example:

```
[1,0,1]
[1,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,1]
```

Below is an example of my code where for

```
# Modified from the code linked above:
def negated_bounded_span(works, start, length):
    sequence = []
    # Left border
    sequence.append(works[start].Not())

    # Middle
    for i in range(1,length+1):
        sequence.append(works[start + i])
    # Right border
    sequence.append(works[start + length + 1].Not())

    return sequence

for n in range(num_nurses):
    # nurse_days[(n,d)] is 1 if nurse n works on day d
    nrses = [nurse_days[(n, d)] for d in range(5)]
    
    for length in range(1, 4):
        for start in range(5 - length - 1):
            model.AddBoolOr(negated_bounded_span(nrses, start, length))
```

A modified excerpt of what the output of the above would look like is the following:

```
['Not(nurse_days_n0d0)', nurse_days_n0d1(0..1), 'Not(nurse_days_n0d2)']
['Not(nurse_days_n0d1)', nurse_days_n0d2(0..1), 'Not(nurse_days_n0d3)']
['Not(nurse_days_n0d2)', nurse_days_n0d3(0..1), 'Not(nurse_days_n0d4)']
['Not(nurse_days_n0d0)', nurse_days_n0d1(0..1), nurse_days_n0d2(0..1), 'Not(nurse_days_n0d3)']
['Not(nurse_days_n0d1)', nurse_days_n0d2(0..1), nurse_days_n0d3(0..1), 'Not(nurse_days_n0d4)']
['Not(nurse_days_n0d0)', nurse_days_n0d1(0..1), nurse_days_n0d2(0..1), nurse_days_n0d3(0..1), 'Not(nurse_days_n0d4)']
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Similar questions reviewed: [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872713/setting-binary-constraints-with-google-or-tools/56877058#56877058)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980487/or-tools-add-2-days-in-a-row-to-the-scheduling-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1)], [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100229/google-or-tools-employee-scheduling-the-condition-does-not-work-properly?rq=1)].

Comment: The requirement is that the nurse works consecutive days regardless of which shift on those days?  I.e. any shift is OK, as long as some shift is taken each day?

Comment: Yes! Basically, once the nurse has been given a shift to work on a day, they have to work every day after that up until some limit. It doesn't matter the shift, but there can be no gaps of days between the start of work and this limit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use/know the syntax of or-tools, but you can probably construct a little boolean logic with constraints to do this.

Let's say we introduce a binary variable to annotate which `d` day that nurse `n` **starts** working:

```
s[n, d] ∈ {0, 1}
```

And to enforce only one sequence of days worked, we need to constrain to one start, for all nurses

```
∑ s[n, d] over all d <= 1    for all n ∈ N
```

Then we know for any particular day, `d` that in order for nurse `n` to be working, they *either* have to start on that day *or* be working the day prior, right?  That's it...

So,

```
working[n, d] <= s[n, d] + working[n, d-1]    for all n ∈ N, d ∈ {d: d ≠ d_0}
```

The constraint for `d_0` is left for the interested coder.  ;)

Comment: I’m following, and this seems like a nice approach. However, I’m struggling to think about how to add the start binary variable - sorry I realise this then enters the or-tools realm again.

Comment: Hmmm.  Can't help there.  Perhaps the reference guide?  OR-Tools seems to have a lot of syntactic sugar over the basics, but this shouldn't be tough to translate from basic math...

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented as follows:

Introduce variables for each employee and day:

`worksOnDay[e, d]` = true if the employee e works any shift on day d.

`workStarted[e, d]` = true if the employee e has started working on day d or earlier.

`okToWork[e, d]` = true if it is OK for employee e to work on day d.

Constrain `worksOnDay[e, d]` to be true if any shift is taken on that day, i.e. boolean OR of the shifts for that day, represented using `AddMaxEquality()` in OR-Tools. `AddMaxEquality()` effectively constrains the target variable to be the OR of the operands.

Constrain `workStarted[e, d]` to be true if it is true on the previous day d-1 or if the day is worked. (On the first day only if the day is worked).

Constrain `okToWork[e, d]` to be true if the work had not already been started on the previous day, or if the previous day is worked. (On the first two days, work is always OK as there can't have been any gap). In other words, if the work had already been started, then it is only OK to work if the previous day is also worked. The expression in pseudo-code would be  `(not  workStarted[e, d - 1]) or (worksOnDay[e, d - 1])`, but since OR-Tools doesn't directly allow such Boolean operators, in the code we have to introduce a helping variable constrained to be `workStarted[e, d - 1].Not()` and use it in the disjunction.

Finally, prevent work on days that it is not allowed by adding the implication that
`worksOnDay[e, d]` implies `okToWork[e, d]`. This constraint will work in both directions and ensure that if `okToWork[e, d]` is false, then `worksOnDay[e, d]` will also be false since otherwise the constraint is violated.

I'm sorry, I work in c# and don't have a working Python installation, but it should be easy enough to code the equivalent constraints in Python. Here's the code:

```
        var model = new CpModel();

        IntVar[,,] work = new IntVar[numEmployees, numShifts, numDays];
        IntVar[,] worksOnDay = new IntVar[numEmployees, numDays];
        IntVar[,] workStarted = new IntVar[numEmployees, numDays];
        IntVar[,] okToWork = new IntVar[numEmployees, numDays];

        foreach (int e in Range(numEmployees))
        {
            foreach (int s in Range(numShifts))
            {
                foreach (int d in Range(numDays))
                {
                    work[e, s, d] = model.NewBoolVar($"work{e}_{s}_{d}");

                }
            }
        }

        for (int e = 0; e < numEmployees; e++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < numDays; d++)
            {
                worksOnDay[e, d] = model.NewBoolVar($"WorksOnDay{e}_{d}");
                workStarted[e, d] = model.NewBoolVar($"WorkStarted{e}_{d}");
                okToWork[e, d] = model.NewBoolVar($"OkToWork{e}_{d}");
            }
        }

        // WorksOnDay is true if any shift is taken on that day
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmployees; e++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < numDays; d++)
            {
                IEnumerable<IntVar> shiftsOnDay = (from int s in Range(numShifts) select work[e, s, d]);
                model.AddMaxEquality(worksOnDay[e, d], shiftsOnDay);
            }
        }

        // On the first day, WorkStarted is true if that day is worked
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmployees; e++)
        {
            model.Add(workStarted[e, 0] == worksOnDay[e, 0]);
        }

        // On subsequent days, WorkStarted is true if the day is worked, or if the work had been started on the day before
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmployees; e++)
        {
            for (int d = 1; d < numDays; d++)
            {
                model.AddMaxEquality(workStarted[e, d], new List<IntVar>() { workStarted[e, d - 1], worksOnDay[e, d] });
            }
        }

        // On the first and second days, there cannot have been a gap, work is always OK
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmployees; e++)
        {
            model.Add(okToWork[e, 0] == 1);
            model.Add(okToWork[e, 1] == 1);
        }

        // For the third day and beyond, work is OK if the work had not been started by the previous day, or if the previous day is worked.
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmployees; e++)
        {
            for (int d = 2; d < numDays; d++)
            {
                IntVar workNotStartedYesterday = model.NewBoolVar("WorkNotStarted");
                model.Add(workNotStartedYesterday == (LinearExpr)workStarted[e, d - 1].Not());
                model.AddMaxEquality(okToWork[e, d], new List<IntVar>() { workNotStartedYesterday, worksOnDay[e, d - 1] });
            }
        }

        // Prevent work on days that it is not allowed
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmployees; e++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < numDays; d++)
            {
                // Working on a day implies that it is OK to work on that day.
                // Stated otherwise, either it is ok to work on the day, or it is not worked on the day.
                model.AddImplication(worksOnDay[e, d], okToWork[e, d]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code doesn't include the "up to some limit of days" requirement which wasn't mentioned in the original question-- it ensures that there are absolutely no gaps at all during the entire scope. Adding the "up to some limit of days" would require an extension.

Comment: I am going through this, but I wanted to confirm that the code allows the start day for each nurse to not be the same. E.g., numDays is say 20 days, where some nurses need to start on day 1 and work consecutively for 5 days. Other nurses may start on day 3, or 7 etc and then work consecutively for 5 days. So in the comment "For the third day and beyond..." does that refer to the third day out of numDays or the third day from the start of work for a specific nurse? (And thank you, I just saw your comment. I have managed to implement the limit of days part).

Comment: The nurses can start on any day, but then must work continuously until they stop; after that they cannot work again. To cover all the shifts it will be necessary in the solution that some start on the first day and others start later.